# Azure Logic App json message grouping with a key

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to group by below JSON Message:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "1",
        "name": "xxx",
        "age": "20"
    },
    {
        "Id": "1",
        "name": "yyy",
        "age": "52"
    },
    {
        "Id": "5",
        "name": "zzz",
        "age": "59"
    }
]
```

to

```
[
    {
        "1": [
            {
                "Id": "1",
                "name": "xxx",
                "age": "20"
            },
            {
                "Id": "1",
                "name": "yyy",
                "age": "52"
            }
        ],
        "5": [
            {
                "Id": "5",
                "name": "zzz",
                "age": "59"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Can someone please help?
JSON Array to another JSON array with group by on fly.
NOTE: I don't want to use the Azure function for this.

Thanks,
Deepak

Comment: Can I ask why not a function?

Comment: Just don't want to complicate this, if possible to achieve in LA, that would be the preferable solution. Maintenance would be in control.

Comment: Soooooo you want to avoid code completely because those maintaining it aren't going to be code literate?  What if you could do it in LA with code but no need for a function?

Comment: Are you open to a third party connector? The one I am proposing you use is quite affordable AND it comes with a whole raft of very useful operations. Depending on how many calls you need per month, it is as cheap as $2 USD a month. In all honesty, to do what you’re asking without the use of a more advanced approach is going to be a pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of how to do it using nothing but standard actions in LogicApps ...

[image]

Create a new LogicApp and load the definition into it via the Code View.

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": [
                    "@variables('Result Object')"
                ],
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_Each_Item": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "For_Each_Item": {
                "actions": {
                    "Does_Current_ID_Exist_In_Result_Object": {
                        "actions": {
                            "Add_Property_(Step_1)": {
                                "inputs": "@setProperty(variables('Result Object'), variables('Current ID'), body('Filter_Data_For_Current_ID'))",
                                "runAfter": {
                                    "Filter_Data_For_Current_ID": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "type": "Compose"
                            },
                            "Add_Property_(Step_2)": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "name": "Result Object",
                                    "value": "@outputs('Add_Property_(Step_1)')"
                                },
                                "runAfter": {
                                    "Add_Property_(Step_1)": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "type": "SetVariable"
                            },
                            "Filter_Data_For_Current_ID": {
                                "inputs": {
                                    "from": "@variables('Data')",
                                    "where": "@equals(item()['Id'], variables('Current ID'))"
                                },
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "Query"
                            }
                        },
                        "expression": {
                            "and": [
                                {
                                    "equals": [
                                        "@variables('Result Object')?[variables('Current ID')]",
                                        "@null"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Set_Current_ID": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "If"
                    },
                    "Set_Current_ID": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "Current ID",
                            "value": "@{item()['Id']}"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "SetVariable"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@variables('Data')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_Current_ID": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "runtimeConfiguration": {
                    "concurrency": {
                        "repetitions": 1
                    }
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Initialize_Current_ID": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Current ID",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_Result_Object": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_Data": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Data",
                            "type": "array",
                            "value": [
                                {
                                    "Id": "1",
                                    "age": "20",
                                    "name": "xxx"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Id": "1",
                                    "age": "52",
                                    "name": "yyy"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Id": "5",
                                    "age": "59",
                                    "name": "zzz"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_Result_Object": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Result Object",
                            "type": "object",
                            "value": {}
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_Data": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {},
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

**`Design:`**

[image]

**`JavaScript:`**

```
const rithinput= [
    {
        "Id": "1",
        "name": "xx",
        "age": "20"
    },
    {
        "Id": "1",
        "name": "yyy",
        "age": "52"
    },
    {
        "Id": "5",
        "name": "zz",
        "age": "59"
    }
];

const group = {};

rithinput.forEach(item => {
    const id = item.Id;
    if (!group[id]) {
        group[id] = [];
    }
    group[id].push(item);
});

const result = [group];

return result;
```

**`Output:`**
[image]

[image]

To execute inline script you need have integration account integrated with logic app.

Comment: Are you using a logic app consumption plan? or something else? I'm getting below error while using execute JS code connector -  The workflow must be associated with an integration account to use the workflow run action 'Execute_JavaScript_Code' of type 'JavaScriptCode'.

Comment: I have mentioned in the answer clearly that you need to have an integrated account and I am using consumption plan. To [integrate account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-create-integration-account?tabs=azure-portal%2Cconsumption) 
 [Image](https://i.imgur.com/ib1MeO7.png)

Comment: Thanks, but is there any alternative way to achieve the same, using without an integration account ?

Comment: No, there is not, you need to use 3rd party connectors which are not free!, any ways glad it helped.